# meteor mongo throws ReferenceError: NumberLong is not defined error while using NumberLong

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to use NumberLong on meteorjs with mongo, but I'm keep getting the following error:
ReferenceError: NumberLong is not defined

Seems like NumberLong is not defined by mongo (just guess).

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was internal issue, the fixtures.js contained NumberLong since one of our developer exported from MongoDB directly to fixtures.js